# Usar date-fns en un proyecto de Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Me gustaría usar la biblioteca date-fns en mi proyecto de Google Apps Script, pero no sé cómo.

He descargado el archivo .js desde aquí: https://www.cdnpkg.com/date-fns/file/date_fns.min.js/

Y lo agregué a mi proyecto como un archivo .gs

Pero ahora no sé cómo referirme a sus funciones. ¿Alguien podría ayudarme por favor?

¡¡Gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Google Apps Script tiene dos "runtimes" el predeterminado es V8, el antiguo está basado en Mozilla Rhino. Lamentablemente ninguno de los dos soporta de manera directa a `date-fns` ni ninguna biblioteca de JavaScript que requiera [módulos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) o [API Web](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API).

Las bibliotecas que usan "Vanilla JavaScript" (JavaScript sin ningúna Web API ni frameworks como jQuery) se pueden importar con el siguiente comando:

```
eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch("my url").getContentText())
```

En el caso de bibliotecas como date-fns que usan import / export y otros comandos no soportados por V8 y/o Rhino deben primero de empaquetarse. Esto lo puedes hacer usando Node.js. Para más detalles https://pulse.appsscript.info/p/2021/07/using-npm-modules-inside-of-google-apps-script/.

Por cierto, en el artículo anterior se menciona https://github.com/classroomtechtools/appsscriptsModules pero el repositorio no include los archivos `*.Bundle.gs`, pero se pueden obtener de la librería de Google Apps Script referida https://script.google.com/home/projects/1flbxyhaMAWh_n_stUeo0GunO_mToDK5wdYR4OJ-3NZzmBX-wsFlqG9Zi/edit. A mí no me ha funcionado. La otra referencia en el artículo aún no la reviso.

Referencias

- https://github.com/classroomtechtools/appsscriptsModules

Relacioando

- [How to load javascript from external source and execute it in Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15548124/1595451)